# Cloudflare Ubuntu 18.04 521 error

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, cloudflare

Всем доброго времени уток!

Сервер держится на node.js 16.8.0.

Безуспешно борюсь с ошибкой 521 на сервере Ubuntu 521 под защитой CloudFlare

```
iptables -L
```

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp spt:http
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp spt:https

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Однако, в браузере всё равно выдаёт
[image: 521 Error]

На CloudFlare ssl сертификат включен.
Такая же беда и по http протоколу

Comment: Ну а на сервере кто-нибудь слушает-то порты 80 и 443?

Comment: express под node.js `app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`App has been started on port ${PORT}...`))`

Comment: А он точно запущен и работает? Без cloudflare открывается?

Comment: @andreymal `pm2 status` `0  │ f5:tree            │ fork     │ 0    │ online    │ 0%       │ 53.1mb`

Comment: @andreymal по ip открывается

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё оказалось просто.
В `/etc/nginx/sites-allowed/default`  указал следующее:

```
ssl_certificate /var/ssl/cert.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /var/ssl/key.pem;

server {
  listen 443 ssl;

  server_name example.com;

  location / {
      proxy_pass http://localhost:5001;
  }
}
```

Где в `ssl_certificate` указан путь до ssl сертификата, а в `ssl_certificate_key` указан путь до приватного ключа ssl сертификата. В `server_name` указываете свой домен, либо поддомен. В `location`->`server_name` порт, на котором держится Ваш node.js сервер. Будьте внимательны и не указываете порт сервера node.js, который уже используется.

Comment: То есть, когда я вас спрашивал про слушание порта 443, вы решили скрыть от меня существование nginx? Нехорошо.

Comment: @andreymal тогда ещё не использовал nginx. Пришёл к нему в ходе изучения